# What will I miss if I skip Pokemon Black/White and go onto Pokemon Black 2/White 2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I was going to buy Pokemon Black/White however I wondered if I should just skip to Black 2/White 2. As far as story goes... well its a Pokemon game not a novel most of the storys in game are just there to hold things together.

Anyway will I be missing anything *important* if I skip to Black/White?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are enough differences between the two to warrant playing both versions, but they're few enough that you can jump straight to White/Black 2 without missing out on anything major.

The region, *Unova*, is generally the same as the first games, however some of the differences are:

- New locations are accessible
- Your journey starts in a new town called *Aspertia City* (*Hiougi Town* in Japanese).
- The Unova Pokedex features 300 Pokemon from the start.
- You will be able to capture pokemons from previous generations from the beginning.
- New forms of the three roaming Pokemon from Black and White: Tornadus, Thundurus and Landorus.
- A new story that takes place 2 years after the events in Black & White
- All of the gyms are either modified or new
- The *Pokewood movie-making minigame* is a new feature to go along with *Pokemon Musicals*.
- Previous Gym Leaders and Champions from other regions can be battled in the World Tournament.
- Keldeo obtains an alternate form by learning the move Sacred Sword.

Possible Spoilers:

> - The storyline involves a new version of Team Plasma.
>  - Characters from the first game return, such as Cheren, Bianca, and N.
>  - Iris replaces Alder as the Unova Region Champion.
>  - Black Kyurem will know the move Freeze Shock, whilst White Kyurem will know the move Ice Burn.
>  - Black Kyurem is related to legendary monster Zekrom and White Kyurem is related to legendary monster Reshiram.

[Source](http://nintendoeverything.com/92566/list-of-differences-between-pokemon-blackwhite-2-and-blackwhite/)

Answer (score 1):

There are certain in-game references to the story of Black and White version that you won't get.  If you have a copy of black or white, you can link it to Black 2 or White 2 (doesn't matter which; I linked my White version to my Black 2 version), and your Black or White character's name will be used in these references.

The story is a continuation of the Black and White.